# Nginx keepalive_requests - What value to use for unlimited?

Tags: nginx, reverse-proxy, keepalive

We are using an nginx backend behind a nginx proxy.

We use upstream keepalives.

They work quite nicely.

We were wondering, what value would we set `keepalive_requests` on the backend to set the maximum number of keepalive requests to unlimited?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no special value to mean unlimited.  Use some big number (up to 2147483647 on 32-bit platforms) instead.

Comment: yep, we have taken a look at the nginx source. nothing in there that would point to a value that sets keepalive_requests to unlimited. this will have to do. thanks!

Comment: Maxim, and what's the point of not having an option to let infinite keep-alive? If a connection is actively used why would it have to be reopen every N http requests?

Comment: @wick, the main reason is that there are some allocations from a connection memory pool which may happen, and the connection have to be closed to free the memory.

Comment: @wick I asked a very similar question: [Why would you ever set MaxKeepAliveRequests to anything but unlimited?](https://superuser.com/q/760509/101823)